# A constant value is expected in string interpolation

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

My code is as follows

```
static string Foo(string str, int width)
{
    return $"{str,width}";
}
```

The compiler isn't letting me use the `width` variable. How can I pass this to a method?

Comment: What do you *expect* that to do? Inside the `{}` should just be a single variable (with optional format string)

Comment: You probably wanted to write the functional equivalent of `return str + "," + width";` which is `return $"{str},{width}";`

Comment: `${string,width}` *is* accepted syntax - the `width` is called "alignment". [See docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#alignment-component). The problem is that it has to be a constant value.

Comment: You could use `return str.PadLeft(width)`. Although there doesn't seem to be any point to making it into a function with a different name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you might be better off to use string.Format than interpolation.

```
var str = "test";
var width = 10;
var fmt = $"{{0,{width}}}";
var result = string.Format(fmt, str);
```

But if you're simply padding with spaces `PadLeft` or `PadRight` would be cleaner...

```
return str.PadLeft(width, ' ');
```

Comment: Did you mean `string.Format(fmt, str)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks @JoeSewell.  I had copied that from a quick test and meant to replace it.